# Config and start liferay 7 + tomcat

Tags: tomcat, liferay

i have a problem with conf and starting liferay 7 (ide eclipse + plugin liferay ide).

Jdk 12.0.2.

can you tell me a complete guide to liferay? I would like to become familiar with this framework. Help me please I can't solve this problem

```
24-Jul-2019 15:19:11.492 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [495] milliseconds
Loading jar:file:/C:/liferay-dxp-7.2.10-ga1/tomcat-9.0.17/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.liferay.petra.reflect.ReflectionUtil (file:/C:/liferay-dxp-7.2.10-ga1/tomcat-9.0.17/lib/ext/com.liferay.petra.reflect.jar) to method java.lang.Object.clone()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.liferay.petra.reflect.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
24-Jul-2019 15:19:12.636 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class [com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener]
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.liferay.petra.reflect.ReflectionUtil.<clinit>(ReflectionUtil.java:160)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.<clinit>(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:479)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5150)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1832)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1577)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at 
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2416)
    at com.liferay.petra.reflect.ReflectionUtil.<clinit>(ReflectionUtil.java:155)
    ... 48 more

24-Jul-2019 15:19:12.638 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
24-Jul-2019 15:19:12.638 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
24-Jul-2019 15:19:12.884 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
24-Jul-2019 15:19:13.001 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [1,506] milliseconds
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're running an unsupported JDK version. Switch to one of the supported JDKs (e.g., JDK 11) listed in Liferay's compatibility matrix: https://web.liferay.com/services/support/compatibility-matrix

For learning about Liferay, please see the documentation at https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-2/user